pandas quantile vs the Excel equivalent calculation difference
There is probably a way to do this the problem is I don't know it. I have data sets that are often between 80 to 120 values long. I am trying to compute the 90% value for each separate data set. I was testing this out in excel and python and realized that there is a difference with the results when I thought I would get the same thing. This difference shows up for me when there are a certain number of data points such as 81, 91, 101, or 111.
I sorted my data smallest to largest. Example data set might be something like:
Samples = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.44, 0.45,
    0.47, 0.54, 0.58, 0.6, 0.68, 0.69, 0.74, 0.82, 0.84, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5,
    1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.9, 2.3, 2.6, 3.5, 4.5, 4.8] 

My conclusion is that Excel produces the right value. The calculation in excel was given to me from someone else. The calculation.:



Description
Calculation
Result




Samples
=COUNT(Samples)
81


0.9 * N samples
= 0.9 * COUNT(Samples)
72.9


Lower
= SMALL(Samples, ROUNDDOWN( K4, 0) )
1.50



So I was told to use Excel, but come on!!! Python can do the same stuff right? Here is my python pandas code:
import pandas as pd
# use the "Samples" from above ⬆️
myS = pd.Series(Samples)
q_lower = myS.quantile(q=0.9, interpolation='lower')
print(q_lower)


Pandas results = 1.7
Okay so I thought maybe numpy (this code is just a guess)
import numpy as np
myindex = int(np.ceil(0.9 * len(Samples))) - 1
print(myS.iloc[myindex])

numpy result 1.7
So why can't I get the same results with excel and python. I prefer python if it can work.

Indices in Python lists starts from 0, so you need to subtract 1 after you find the index. You also don't need numpy or pandas for that, just get the result of length * 0.9, round down and subtract 1
print(Samples[int(len(Samples) * 0.9) - 1]) # 1.5

